# Ambiguous use of subscript. Array Swift IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I try to compile on device but i get this error. Any help?. In the simulator works perfectly.

I get an ambiguous use of subscript error in the following code and was hoping somebody else has encountered this and know the fix.

```
 case .Success:
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                      print ("Respuesta 200")
                    if let value = response.result.value {

                        let respuestaJSON = JSON(value)
                        let objsonUSUARIOS = respuestaJSON["d"].object
                        let arrayUsuarios = objsonUSUARIOS["results"]!
                        //print ("Usuarios: ",String(arrayUsuarios))

                        for  i in 0 ..< arrayUsuarios!.count{
                            let boletines = boletinJSON()

                            if  let item = arrayUsuarios![i] as? [String: AnyObject]{
                                )

                                if let person = item["Title"] as? String
                                {
                                    boletines.name = person

                                }

                                if let person = item["Portada"] as? String
                                {
                                    boletines.imagen = person

                                }

                                if let person = item["Created"] as? String
                                {
                                    boletines.fecha = person
                                }

                                if let person = item["AttachmentFiles"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                                    if let itemAttach = person["__deferred"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
                                        if let itemdeferred = itemAttach["uri"] as? String {
                                            boletines.urldescarga = itemdeferred
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                self.boletin.append(boletines)
                                self.view.hideToastActivity()

                            }

                        }



                    }
                      self.tableView.reloadData()

                    //  self.view.hideToastActivity()
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inform the compiler what the intermediary object `objsonUSUARIOS` is of type

```
let objsonUSUARIOS = respuestaJSON["d"].object
```

After the above statement, the compiler does not know what kind of object he is dealing with. So make sure that you can actually **do all the casting** as below

```
let objsonUSUARIOS = respuestaJSON["d"].object as! Dictionary
let arrayUsuarios = objsonUSUARIOS["results"]! as! Array
```

Comment: ok thanks But in this line " let arrayUsuarios = objsonUSUARIOS["results"]! as! NSDictionary" i get  "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x10a907d68) to 'NSDictionary'" when i changed "object" for " .object as! NSDictionary"

Comment: Cast it to `Array`. `let arrayUsuarios = objsonUSUARIOS["results"]! as! NSArray`

Comment: Please do not suggest `NSArray / NSDictionary`. Use Swift native types

Comment: @FireUser, Use `Dictionary ` and `Array` instead of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` respectively. @Vadian Thanks mate.

Comment: when i used  Dictionary and Array I get an ambiguous use of subscrip

Comment: Array is a generic container that holds values of a specific type. So you can have an Array<Int> that holds integers, or an Array<String>, or according to your requirement. You can also solve the problem by using `NSArray`, as NSArray doesn’t use generics.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have not specified the type of object `arrayUsuarios` is `Array`, so try to explicit type cast the `arrayUsuarios` Array

```
let arrayUsuarios = objsonUSUARIOS["results"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
```

Comment: perfect but i get this advert: Conditional cast from '[String : AnyObject]' to '[String : AnyObject]' always succeeds

Comment: Instead of `if  let item = arrayUsuarios![i] as? [String: AnyObject]{` just write like this `item = arrayUsuarios![i]`

Comment: i changed but i get  Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[[String : AnyObject]]'

Comment: I  change to "let arrayUsuarios = objsonUSUARIOS["results"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]" and "if let item = arrayUsuarios![i] " but not working.

Comment: No need to write `if let` just write directly `let item = arrayUsuarios![i]`